# Use multiple docker images at once

Tags: docker, tensorflow, ros

I am trying to containerize my ROS + tensorflow application. The problem is that I want to use GPU. I can either use GPU and forget about ROS, or use ROS and forget about GPU, but I don't know how I can enable both of them.

I have tried starting FROM a cuda image and installing ROS as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu), but the ros couldn't be installed, not being able to find the package.

I also tried building them one by one in the same Dockerfile and copying all the ROS-related stuff from a ROS build, but that failed too.

Ideally, I want to make it work as if I "include" a Cuda image and a ROS image, but resource on building from multiple images like this could hardly be found. Any help or pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: I would advise you yo start with `tensorflow` image you'd like and installing ROS on top of that. You should provide your current `Dockerfile` and errors it produces though.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke There were some hiccups, but your suggestion eventually worked out. Thank you.